# Is there any reason this VEX RobotC code should NOT engage the motor when the sonar sensor detects something?

Tags: ultrasonic-sensors, robotc, vex

I have the following code set up to run a simple test bed -- it's using VEX robotics Cortex 2.0, natural language PLTW. (Yes, I know it's old and now no longer supported, etc. etc. That isn't the point).

```
#pragma config(Sensor, dgtl6,  lite,           sensorLEDtoVCC)
#pragma config(Sensor, dgtl7,  Zonar,          sensorSONAR_cm)
#pragma config(Motor,  port1,           Wheel,         tmotorVex393_HBridge, openLoop)
#pragma config(Motor,  port10,          Klaw,          tmotorVex393_HBridge, openLoop)
//*!!Code automatically generated by 'ROBOTC' configuration wizard               !!*//

task main()
{
  while (1==1)
  {
    while (SensorValue(Zonar) >= 20)
    {
      turnLEDOff(lite);
      stopMotor(Wheel); 
    }
    turnLEDOn(lite);
    startMotor(Wheel, 63);
  }
}
```

What is supposed to happen is that when you pass something <20 cm in front of the ultrasonic sensor the wheel should engage and the light go on. In a few cases tho (I built several test beds and have a class doing this to practice input/ outputs) the motor doesn't engage but the light goes on. I thought I might just have to swap the order, but I feel like there is some dead simple thing I am missing here. I am having students essentially copy this code; the point of the exercise is more to just get a feel for writing this stuff and doing the procedural things to get robots working, and use simple while loops. I had similar code for the first part which was just engaging the button (instead of a SensorValue with a sonar I just had a button that was equal to 1 or 0) and that worked fine (you push the button and the motor runs). But I feel like there's a reason this one seems to be a bit wonkier and I wonder if it's something like mis-using while loops or that an if-then-else would be better.

Anyhow any advice would be appreciated.

EDIT: As it happens we had some bad sensors and that was messing up results, and thanks for the "look at the hardware" suggestion!

Comment: remove all code except the "motor on command"  ... does the motor run?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics*, Jesse. I'd second @jsotola's recommendation here - first troubleshoot the motor itself. If you run `startMotor(Wheel,63);
wait(3.25);
stopMotor(Wheel);` and nothing else, does the motor engage? You have `Wheel` configured to `port1` - is it actually plugged into port 1? Is your battery charged? A motor will draw significantly more power than an LED, so if the batteries are weak it's entirely possible to have the light turn on and no motor motion. Please try running the code to run only the motor and *edit your question* with the results of that test.

Comment: thanks to you both. I should have thought of that, though I should say I tried one code set on a couple of different test beds and got odd results, but the basic hardware stuff I should definitely do.

Comment: Perhaps the sonar distance is right on the edge, so a small amount of noise is rapidly turning it on and off. It's easy to see an LED as "on" when it's rapidly turning on and off, but some motor controllers will, when rapidly switching on and off, leave the motor off.